# Android: How do I "properly" create a publicly readable file?

Tags: android, file, io, permissions

My app must create files that can then be easily read/written/copied from a connected PC. I've read everything I can find, and tried everything recommended by online comments and the Android docs, but I just can't get it to work.

I am successfully creating and writing to files. Using ADB's shell I can see the files are there, but from (for example) Windows I can see every file in the directory EXCEPT the ones I'm creating. Files copied to the Android device from (say) Windows are publicly visible. But files my apps create - even if in the exact same directory - are not. Since I know the files are there but visibility is selective, I presume this is a permissions problem.

Digging more, I found Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE and _WRITABLE but "This constant was deprecated in API level 17" so this approach is clearly not the way to go. I also tried File.setReadable and File.setWritable on the existing files but both fail and return false.

Yes, the app has "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (or it wouldn't be writing to the external storage). It can create the files, they're just not publicly visible.

I haven't been able to find any file creation methods that have any provision for explicitly creating publicly-accessible files except for File and Context which have problems as noted above. It looks like there have been multiple ways to do this over the years but they've either been deprecated, don't work, or I'm not using them properly.

So... what is the proper and supported way to create publicly-accessible files in Android's external storage? Thanks!

*Edit: Code added. Nothing fancy, just proof of concept stuff at the moment. Again, this DOES successfully create files on the Android in the specified directory... but those files are not visible to outside devices when connected via USB, either "as a camera" nor "as a media device". All other directories and files are visible to the external device, just not those created by my app.*

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    filename = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/test.txt");

    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(filename); // use a FileWriter since we're using a String
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        writer.write(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29). An example of its use:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(data);
...
```

Comment: As shown in the code above, I'm already using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). However, I revised the code to try your getExternalFilesDir(). No errors resulted, but if the file was created it's not even visible to ADB (!?!). The resulting filespec was "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.project.TortureTest/files/test.txt". The file is indeed there. However, the "Android" directory and below isn't visible to the PC.

Comment: I'm thinking that the code needs to explicitly specify that the file being created should be publicly accessible. I find it significant that there used to be an official way to do this via Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE but now that's been deprecated. I suspect there's another way to forcefully declare that when creating a file, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the files being not displayed in Windows might well be caused by the MTP connection. I have repeatedly experienced that files I create while the device is connected to the PC are only visible to Windows after I disconnect and reconnect the device.

Second, you can easily create files on the external storage using a combination of File and OutputStream:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.txt");
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
//write data
stream.close
```

Comment: I am successfully creating files. They're just not visible to other devices. Good idea on the reconnect, but I just tried it and the files are still not visible even after Windows reestablishes the connection. The other directories and files are visible, including those copied TO the Android from the computer, but the ones created by the Android itself are not.

Comment: I have confirmed that the "ADB pull" command can indeed successfully transfer files created by the app to the PC. So in addition to the ADB shell being able to see them, ADB pull can read and transfer them. But they are still not visible over a USB connection to a PC. Doing an ls -la on the file yields: "-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r       37 2014-01-25 17:53 test.txt"

Comment: That's really strange. I am using the very same code as I added above and it works just fine.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's a PC or Windows driver problem. Everything points to Android doing things properly: The file is created, does have content, is visible in ADB, has the same permissions as other files in that directory, etc. Obviously it's an "Android problem" in the sense that we need to resolve it given the popularity of Windows, but I suspect the technical issue lies with Windows. Research continues....

Comment: {sigh} Thought I had it with MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(), which supposedly forces the Android filesystem to rescan one or more directories. Various online comments suggested this is necessary to cause Android to inform the connected device (PC) of changes in the directory. Coded it in, it executed without errors, but no improvement. Still digging....

Comment: Also tried .scanFile() with an explicit MIMEtype of "text/plain" instead of passing null and letting the function discern the file extensions as described in the docs. Still no joy.

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug in Android that has been ignored by Google for well over a year now. See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282 for an interesting conversation on this topic.